# Make a sliding panel unresponsive if input text is missing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple example of a some user input and a button that when clicked reveals "Hello World":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style> 


input {
    border: solid 4px green;

}

button {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
    border: solid 4px darkblue;
    color: white;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: green;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="client_input">
        <label>Column1</label>
        <input type="text" class="column1" id="column1" name="column1" required>
        <label>Column2</label>
        <input type="text" class="column2" name="column2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="samplebtn">slide</button>        
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
```

The script used for the sliding effect is written in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    $(".samplebtn").click(function() {
        $(".panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to prevent the slide button to work if there is user input in the input elements and at the same time if the button is pressed it should make an alert indicating that the user input need to be added first. This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if ($(".client_input input").is(":empty")) {
                $(".samplebtn").click(function) {
                    alert("Input client information first")
                };
                $(".samplebtn").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {                
                $(".samplebtn").click(function() {
                    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                    $(".panel").slideToggle();
                });
            }; 
        });
```

However, I think I have the order of functions wrong or something, because I am getting the undesired result. Any suggestions to the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".panel").hide();

    $('.samplebtn').on('click',function(){
     var error = false;
     
     $.each($('input'),function(a,b){
      if($(b).val() == "")
      {
        error = true;
      }
     });
     
     if(error){
        alert("Input client information first");
     }else{
        $(".panel").slideToggle();
     }
     
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style> 


input {
    border: solid 4px green;

}

button {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
    border: solid 4px darkblue;
    color: white;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: green;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="client_input">
        <label>Column1</label>
        <input type="text" class="column1" id="column1" name="column1" required>
        <label>Column2</label>
        <input type="text" class="column2" name="column2" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="samplebtn">slide</button>        
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
```

You need to check your inputs on button clicked, not on document ready

Comment: is the `$.each` intentional without anything after the $.